# MouseEvent and Onclick

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I made a rating system that shows 5 stars when users mouse over, the stars turn yellow, but when user mouse-out, the stars turn white.

However, I want to make a function that when user click on the star it turn yellow and never turn back to white even when the mouse-out. I try to use mouse-down to do it, but the mouse-out event still comes out.

```
<script>
function changeImage1() {
        document.getElementById('myImage1').src="yellow.jpg";}

function reset(){
document.getElementById('myImage1').src= "whitestar.jpg";}
</script>

<body>
<img id="myImage1" onmouseover="changeImage1()" onmouseout="reset()" width="150" height="150"src="whitestar.jpg">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test in mouse out for yellow, and then return false?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="myImage1" width="150" height="150">
<script>
    var img = document.getElementById('myImage1');
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', changeImage1, false);
    img.addEventListener('mouseout', reset, false);
    img.addEventListener('click', click_, false);

    function changeImage1() {
        img.src = 'yellow.jpg';
    }
    function reset() {
        img.src = 'whitestar.jpg';
    };
    function click_() {
        img.removeEventListener('mouseover', changeImage1, false);
        img.removeEventListener('mouseout', reset, false);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the explanation of the problem and the solution?

Comment: Problem:: event fires when we don't want it,
Solution:: removing unwanted events

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information.

Comment: Problem nr.2:: bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery click event handler

```
<img id="myImage" src="whitestar.jpg">
```

Assign the click handler for the img element

```
$( "#myImage" ).click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src','yellow.jpg');

});
```

**EDITED WITHOUT JQUERY**

```
<img onclick="this.src='yellow.jpg';" id="myImage" src="whitestar.jpg">
```

Comment: From the [tag:javascript] tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* . The question is not tagged with jQuery, so please don't provide a jQuery answer *or* add add a pure JS solution at least.